# Monitor registry key with reactive extensions

Tags: windows, registry, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I would like to track changes to a registry key, for instance addition/removal of a subkey, addition/removal/edition of a value. How could I create an IObservable sequence that exposes these changes?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to p/invoke the [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892(v=vs.85).aspx), a Win32 function which notifies the caller about changes to the attributes or contents of a specified registry key. This function sets an event whenever it detects a change. Note that it it must be called on a persistent thread, otherwise it will signal whenever the thread exits (even though no change happened). See below for a possible implementation of this with Rx.Net.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Win32;

public class RegistryMonitoringOperations
{
    [Flags]
    public enum RegChangeNotifyFilter
    {
        /// <summary>Notify the caller if a subkey is added or deleted.</summary>
        Key = 1,
        /// <summary>Notify the caller of changes to the attributes of the key,
        /// such as the security descriptor information.</summary>
        Attribute = 2,
        /// <summary>Notify the caller of changes to a value of the key. This can
        /// include adding or deleting a value, or changing an existing value.</summary>
        Value = 4,
        /// <summary>Notify the caller of changes to the security descriptor
        /// of the key.</summary>
        Security = 8
    }

    private const int KeyQueryValue = 0x0001;
    private const int KeyNotify = 0x0010;
    private const int StandardRightsRead = 0x00020000;

    public static IObservable<Unit> CreateKeyValuesChangedObservable(
        RegistryHive hive,
        string subKey,
        RegChangeNotifyFilter filter,
        IScheduler registrationScheduler)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Unit>(
            obs =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var key = OpenKey(hive, subKey);
                        return new CompositeDisposable(
                            CreateKeyValuesChangedObservable(key, filter).SubscribeOn(registrationScheduler).Subscribe(obs),
                            Disposable.Create(() => RegCloseKey(key)));
                    }
                    catch (Win32Exception e)
                    {
                        obs.OnError(e);
                        return Disposable.Empty;
                    }
                });
    }

    private static IDisposable SetCallbackWhenSignalled(WaitHandle waitObject, Action action)
    {
        var registeredWait = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitObject, (s, t) => action(), null, -1, true);
        return Disposable.Create(() => registeredWait.Unregister(null));
    }

    private static IObservable<Unit> CreateKeyValuesChangedObservable(IntPtr key, RegChangeNotifyFilter filter)
    {
        return Observable.Create<Unit>(
            obs =>
                {
                    var eventNotify = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                    var result = RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(key, true, filter, eventNotify.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), true);
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        obs.OnError(new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                    }
                    return new CompositeDisposable(
                        eventNotify,
                        SetCallbackWhenSignalled(
                            eventNotify,
                            () =>
                                {
                                    obs.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                                    obs.OnCompleted();
                                }));
                }).Repeat();
    }

    private static IntPtr OpenKey(RegistryHive hive, string subKey)
    {
        IntPtr registryKey;
        var result = RegOpenKeyEx((int)hive, subKey, 0, StandardRightsRead | KeyQueryValue | KeyNotify, out registryKey);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        return registryKey;
    }
```

Here's a typical usage of this function:

```
 RegistryMonitoringOperations.CreateKeyValuesChangedObservable(
                RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                "somepath",
                RegistryMonitoringOperations.RegChangeNotifyFilter.Value,
                DispatcherScheduler.Instance)
```

As you can see above, one way to avoid dedicating a thread for calling this function is to use the UI thread which is persistent (so in rx terms, using the dispatcher scheduler). RegNotifyChangeKeyValue returns immediatly when in asynchronous mode so it won't block the UI.